# NextJS: Epoch time to date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, next.js

I have this NextJS app where I have a date in the div.

```
<div>{post.createdat}</div>
```

It will show a date like this 1609553315666, which is epoch time since 1970.

Is there a way to directly convert epoch to date inline with something like this:

```
<div>{post.createdat.toDate().substring(5,12)}</div>
```

so that it will show May 13 2021.

Comment: take a look at  intl module i think i can help you Intl.DateTimeFormat

Answer (score 0):

Maybe can't do it inline.  I have converted it like this but not inline.

```
  var d = new Date(data.createdat)
  const value = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(d))
  post.createdat = value.substring(0, 10)
```

For NextJS, it has to be in json style.

Comment: Given *d* is a *Date* object, then `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(d))` produces another Date as if by `new Date(d)`, so it's just a verbose way of copying *d*. If *data.createdat* is a time value and you want to get the related UTC date, then:`new Date(data.createdat).toISOString().substring(0,10)` will do.